# Call a function with list or splat arguments

Tags: vim

Is there a way to call a vim function with a list of arguments. My list of arguments is coming from a optional splat arguments in another function, and I need a way to pass these arguments to the target function.

The target function is,

```
function! run_hello(cmd, ...)
  echo 'run_hello'
  echo a:cmd
  echo a:000
endfunction
```

The function that will call `run_hello` is,

```
function! hello(...)
  call run_hello('foo', the splats here)
endfunction
```

It will be called like so, with different arguments.

```
call hello('lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor')
```

I am currently using `hello(arglist)` and passing the `a:000` list forward. But I would like to know if it is possible to call a function with a list as arguments, that then become it's regular argument list.

Something like JavaScript's,

```
foo.apply(this, ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The equivalent of JavaScript's `apply()` is `call()` in Vimscript:

```
function! hello(...)
    call call('run_hello', ['foo'] + a:000)
endfunction
```

This is no typo: You `:call` the function named `call()`.